# WCF call sometime slow on servers side (Windbg help)

Tags: performance, wcf, windbg

I am using WCF 4 deployed in IIS 8 on a win 2008 server (4 core). 
 All my services are using default parameters for *instancemode, concurrencymode* and *throttling* values.

Multiples application (70 clients) are calling on each 10 seconds an operation (getStatusData) that should return a small array of result (1 kb).
 This is a scheduled call to keep the clients updated by polling...

In the service application logs on server side I could see that sometimes the server take a little more than 30 seconds to answer (as is it blocked in the middle of the response...)

Recently I have loadbalanced my service and used Redis as a distributed cache.
 Since then all my clients have reported a slow behavior and the operation getStatusData is taking now sometime more than 3 minutes to complete on server side causing an exception timeout on client side.

I have changed the application behavior in order to call this operation each 2 minutes and it seems that I am back where I was : the operation takes sometimes 30 seconds to achieve its work...

I want to know why I observe such behavior in order to poll again at each 10 seconds ( with 2 minutes data is too old) and speed up my service.

**Added info :**

In order to give some more information about possible bottleneck, I have took a dump of my process running when it was performing slowly, and here the info about the threadpool info :

```
0:000> !threadpool
CPU utilization: 24%
Worker Thread: Total: 28 Running: 0 Idle: 28 MaxLimit: 8191 MinLimit: 8
Work Request in Queue: 0
--------------------------------------
Number of Timers: 2
--------------------------------------
Completion Port Thread:Total: 80 Free: 4 MaxFree: 16 CurrentLimit: 80 MaxLimit: 1000 MinLimit: 8
```

Have you got any idea on what is going on here ?

Comment: Are your clients only doing a read of data or are they also writing data?  What I read Redis may go single threaded on writes.

Comment: The clients are reading/writing (the same table is updated) : I have some contention on this table but no more than the version without Redis. Redis is also used as read/write and effectively Redis could be a bottleneck.... Another observation I had make : all calls duration seems to be increasing regurarly then go down : eg first call takes few milliseconds, then 1 second, 2, ...30,..., 1 min and then again we start again to respond with few ms....

Comment: I'd recommend talking to the guys that did Redis.  It sounds like you are single threading through Redis.  Also see if you can observer the same thing on the server side.  Are the writes getting longer and longer between transmissions?  If so I'd say it definitely points at Redis